# How to bind an image within a Tkinter Text widget to an event?

Tags: python, tkinter

As you can see from the following code I have bound the text label to the function `prt()`.

I want the same binding to be applied to the image.

I've tried creating a tag for the image but there doesn't seem to be an option.

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def prt (txt):
    print(txt)

root = tk.Tk()

i = Image.open("image_name/path")
retweet_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)

text = tk.Text(root, height = 5, width = 10, cursor ="hand2")
text.pack()
text.insert(tk.END, "Press\n", "txt_click")
text.tag_bind("txt_click", "<Button-1>", lambda event: prt("TEXT BIND WORKS"))
text.image_create("2.0", image=retweet_img)
text.tag_bind(retweet_img, "<Button-1>", lambda  event: prt("IMAGE BIND WORKS"))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text widget tags are assigned over ranges of indices. Create and configure the tag then apply it to the range that includes your image. eg:

```
tag = "RETWEET"
index = "2.0"
imgname = text.image_create(index, image=retweet_img)
text.tag_add(tag, index, "{0} + 1 char".format(index))
text.tag_bind(tag, "<Button-1>", on_image_click)
```

Images take up one char