# Tkinter- How to display picture inside text widget at right position

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a simple chatting app for now it is only sending and receiving messages but i want to add some more functionality in it and want to share pictures and images. I tried to build some logic but i am still on the way my issue is how can i display picture inside chat box like we do in different chatting apps. Below is my code for this kindly point out what is wrong in it because when i run code and upload image it displayed at chat box but when i upload another image first one got vanished.

```
def open_img ( self) :
    global img
    f_types = [ ('Jpg Files' , '*.jpg'), ('Png Files' , '*.png'), ('Jpeg Files' , '*.jpeg') ]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename ( filetypes = f_types )
    img =  PIL.Image.open ( filename )
    img_resized = img.resize ( (200 , 100) )  # new width & height
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage ( img_resized )
    self.text_box.image_create ( END , image = img )


    
    self.text_box.insert(END , "\n")

    
   

    self.text_box.tag_configure ( "right" , justify = 'right' )
    self.text_box.tag_configure ( "right" , foreground = 'slate blue2' )
    
    self.text_box.configure ( state = DISABLED )
    self.text_box.see ( END )
```

This is my function to upload and display image inside textbox.
these are the outputs.
[image]

above output when i upload first picture but when i again upload any picture it give this type of output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image disappears because you are not saving a reference to the previous image, and then it gets garbage collected. You can fix this by creating a list to hold all image references and then just append every new image to this list.

In the `__init__()` method:

```
self.image_list = []
```

In the `open_img()` method:

```
self.image_list.append(img)
```

Comment: can we convert image to clickable image means by clicking on the image we get some type of result?

Comment: As far as I can see the Text widget was not really meant for this type of interaction. However it seems that you could work it; have a look at [How to bind an image within a Tkinter Text widget to an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070786/8172933).

Comment: almost done with my task with your now i have only one when i upload image it automatically open the image in a image viewer but i want image to open in a image viewer when i click on it.  this is my code     `self.text_box.image_create ( END ,image = img  )     fop = open ( file , "rb" )     def onclick():  os.startfile(file, 'open')    self.text_box.bind("<Button-1>" ,onclick())`

Comment: Please start a new question instead of continuing in comments.

Comment: here is the link of my [new-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053156/tkinter-unable-to-bind-image-with-an-event)  kindly look into it