# Tkinter- unable to bind image with an event

Tags: tkinter

I have created a chat app where i want to share images and pictures as well and i am displaying picture on the chat box every thing is going right till here but i want when any one click on displayed image or picture it will open in an image viewer for this i took help from this question and try something [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070292/how-to-bind-an-image-within-a-tkinter-text-widget-to-an-event/49070786#49070786](https://How%20to%20bind%20an%20image%20within%20a%20Tkinter%20Text%20widget%20to%20an%20event?)

when  i run the code picture open right after displaying on chat box but i want to open picture when someone click on it.
here is my code:

```
import functools
import json
import sys
from functools import partial
import tooltip as t
from tkinter import *
from upload import *
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
import os
import pathlib
import cgitb
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import threading
import ctypes
cgitb.enable ( )
class ChatInterface ( Frame ) :

  def __init__ ( self , master = None ) :
    Frame.__init__ ( self , master )
    self.imglist = [ ]
    self.master = master

    # sets default bg for top level windows


    self.text_frame = Frame ( self.master , bd = 6 , bg = "black" )
    self.text_frame.pack ( expand = True , fill = BOTH )

    self.text_box_scrollbar = Scrollbar ( self.text_frame , bd = 0 , bg = "#426CB4" )
    self.text_box_scrollbar.pack ( fill = Y , side = RIGHT )

    self.text_box = Text ( self.text_frame , yscrollcommand = self.text_box_scrollbar.set , state = DISABLED ,
                           bd = 1 , padx = 6 , pady = 6 , spacing3 = 8 , wrap = WORD , bg = "black" ,
                           font = "Times 10" , relief = GROOVE ,
                           width = 10 , height = 1 , fg = "white" )

    self.text_box.pack ( expand = True , fill = BOTH )
    self.text_box_scrollbar.config ( command = self.text_box.yview )

    self.entry_frame = Frame ( self.master , bd = 1 , bg = "black" )
    self.entry_frame.pack ( side = LEFT , fill = BOTH , expand = True )

    self.entry_field = Entry ( self.entry_frame , bd = 1 , justify = LEFT )

    self.entry_field.pack ( fill = X , padx = 6 , pady = 6 , ipady = 3 )



    self.upload_button_frame = Frame ( self.master , bd = 0 , bg = 'black' )
    self.upload_button_frame.pack ( fill = BOTH )

    self.pic_button = Button ( self.upload_button_frame , text = 'upload' ,
                               relief = GROOVE ,
                               borderwidth = 0 , bg = 'slateblue2' , bd = 0 , fg = "Black" ,
                               command = lambda : self.open_img ( ) , activebackground = "black" ,
                               activeforeground = "#000000" )
    self.pic_button.pack ( in_ = self.upload_button_frame , side = RIGHT )
    self.master.bind ( "<Return>" , self.open_img )
    self.pictccp = t.CreateToolTip ( self.pic_button , "Click here to share pictures" )






  def open_img ( self ) :

    global img
    tag = "imageclick"
    index = "2.0"
    f_types = [ ('Jpg Files' , '*.jpg') , ('Png Files' , '*.png') , ('Jpeg Files' , '*.jpeg') ]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename ( filetypes = f_types )
    file = pathlib.PurePath ( filename )
    fop = open ( file , "rb" )
    img = PIL.Image.open ( filename )
    img_resized = img.resize ( (200 , 100) )  # new width & height
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage ( img_resized )

    self.text_box.configure ( state = NORMAL )
    self.text_box.image_create ( END , image = img )

    fop = open ( file , "rb" )

    def onclick ( ) :
      os.startfile ( file , 'open' )


    self.text_box.insert ( END , "\n" )

    self.text_box.bind ( "<Button-1>" , onclick ( ) )


    self.text_box.tag_configure ( "right" , justify = 'right' )
    self.text_box.tag_configure ( "right" , foreground = 'slate blue2' )
    self.text_box.tag_add ( "right" , 1.0 , "end" )
    self.text_box.configure ( state = DISABLED )
    self.text_box.see ( END )
    self.imglist.append ( img )








  

def chating ( ) :
  root = Tk()

  a = ChatInterface ( root )
  root.geometry ( "340x500" )
  root.title ( "Chat" )
  root.mainloop ( )

chating()
```

Comment: This code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports needed for it to run. The code indentation is also corrupt.

Comment: @figbeam i have updated the question and now you can run this code

Comment: @sam You clearly have not checked the link they provided above. The example you provided should be reproducible and also **minimal**. You are importing many third party libraries here which are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Billy i have removed unnecessary imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a general solution for opening an image by clicking on it while in a Text widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, padx=10, pady=5, cursor ="hand2")
text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
tag_dict = dict()   # Holds path to images in the Text widget

def click(tag):
    print(f'Clicked on {tag}')
    info = tag_dict.get(tag, False)
    if info:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        filepath = os.path.join(cwd, info)
        os.startfile(filepath)  # Start default program and load image

# Add some text and tag it
tag = 'Text1'
text.insert(tk.END, "The first text\n", tag)
text.tag_bind(tag, "<Button-1>", lambda event, tag=tag: click(tag))

# Add an image and tag it
pilimg = Image.open('images/chapman.png')  # Relative path to image file
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilimg)
image_start_index = text.index(tk.INSERT)   # Save INSERT index before image
tag = "Image1"
tag_dict[tag] = 'images/chapman.png'    # Save file path to tag_dict
imgname = text.image_create(tk.END, image=image1)
image_stop_index = text.index(tk.INSERT)    # Save INSERT index after image
text.tag_add(tag, image_start_index, image_stop_index)  # Tag image
text.tag_bind(tag, "<Button-1>", lambda event, tag=tag: click(tag))
text.insert(tk.END, "\n")   # Add newline after image

# Add some text and tag it
tag = 'Text2'
text.insert(tk.END, "The second text\n", tag)
text.tag_bind(tag, "<Button-1>", lambda event, tag=tag: click(tag))

root.mainloop()
```

Is this what you have in mind?